# Simple click event not working in JS

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I have created a very simple fiddle in JsFiddle. To my surprise it is not working. Please let me know if I am mistaking anything.

HTML-

```
<button onclick="test1()">
Push
</button>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="test1()"/>
```

JS-

```
function test1(){
    alert("1");
}
```

I want to show a simple alert on button click but it is not showing up.

Please click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oz56qa6s/) to see this simple fiddle.

Comment: `onclick` not `onclcik`

Comment: correct the typo

Comment: It doesn't work even after correcting typo.

Comment: It works fine for me. Where is your JS located? Check the console output.

Comment: Console says test1 is undefined. I am using JsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at your browsers web console you can see an `Uncaught ReferenceError` is thrown. It tells you that function `test1` is not defined.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13791292/4256737) answer the same error is discussed.
The problem is, that the javascript file is linked into the html header and called before the html code is initialized.
The answer suggest to use jquery and its corresponding `ready` function.

If you want to do plain javascript you can solve this issue by directly embedding your code into your html using a script tag.

Take a look at the following snippet.

```html
<button onclick="test1()">
Push
</button>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="test1()"/>
<script>
function test1(){
 alert("1");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the function inside the script tag as shown in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oz56qa6s/7/).

```
<button onclick="test1()">
  Push
 </button>
 <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="test1()"/>
<script>
function test1(){
    alert("1");
}
</script>
```