# Getting a reference error while calling a function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call `'A' function` from `'B' function` in `JQuery`. The function `'A`' is defined before the `'B'` function. But whenever I try to run the `'B'` functions script, I am getting a reference error : `'A' function not defined`.

Here is the code of both `'A'` as well as `'B'` function.

**Here**

> 'A'= calcGST(); & 'B'=SetDefault();

I have also attached the console's error below.

```
function SetDefault(a, Text)
{

   var z = Number(1); 
   console.log("count"+$("#icount").val());
   console.log("count "+$("#icount").val());
   var subtot=0;var TaxAmt=0;
   for(z=1; z<=$("#icount").val();z++)
   {

       var inv = $("#invqty"+z).val();           
       if(inv==null)
       {
      inv=0;
   }             

       var rt= $("#rate"+z).val();

       if(rt==null)
       {
          rt=0;
       }

           var at = inv*rt;

           $("#amt"+z).val(at);
           subtot=at+subtot;

   }
   console.log(subtot);
   document.getElementById("subtot").value=subtot;
   calcGST();


}
```

**Here is my calcGST()-**

```
function calcGST()
{
    var hsncode = $("input[name='hsncode[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
              console.log("HSNCode "+ hsncode);
    var hsnper = $("input[name='hsnper[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
              console.log("HSNPer "+ hsnper);
    var hsnamt = $("input[name='amt[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
          console.log("HSNAmt "+ hsnamt);


functionToSetAllGstValue(hsnamt, hsncode, hsnper);
//alert("Called");

 document.getElementById("gtotal1").value=0.0;
   var cgst_per = document.getElementById("cgst").value;//Central Tax Percent
  console.log("cgst_per"+cgst_per);
  var sgst_per = document.getElementById("sgst").value;//State Tax Percent

  var subtot = document.getElementById("subtot").value;//Sub Total
  console.log("subtot"+subtot);
   var sgst_amt=((sgst_per/100)*subtot); 
   console.log("sgst_amt"+ sgst_amt);
  document.getElementById("sgstamt").value=sgst_amt.toFixed(2);
   var cgst_amt=((cgst_per/100)*subtot);
  document.getElementById("cgstamt").value=cgst_amt.toFixed(2);
  var gtotal = Number(subtot)+Number(cgst_amt)+Number(sgst_amt);
   //var ramt=gtotal-($subtotal+taxamt+cgst+sgst);
   gtotal = Math.round(gtotal);
  //alert("gtotal "+gtotal);
   document.getElementById("gtotal1").value = gtotal.toFixed(2);

    var ramt=gtotal-(Number(subtot)+Number(cgst_amt)+Number(sgst_amt));
    document.getElementById("ramt").value = ramt.toFixed(2);

    //alert(ramt.toFixed(2));

}
```

**Here is my console error :**

```
ReferenceError: calcGST is not defined[Learn More]  new_tax_invoice.php:853:4
SetDefault http://vijayneetigroup.com/ERP/rugwed/pages/new_tax_invoice.php:853:4
onchange http://vijayneetigroup.com/ERP/rugwed/pages/new_tax_invoice.php:1:1
```

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which files you have defined these function? and In what scope?

Comment: In the same file sir. Both the functions are in same file.

Comment: Check if there is an error in the calcGST function. is your setAllToGstValue function defined?

Comment: Yes, I have defined setAllToGstValue function defined. But I did not post it because the question would have been pretty lengthy.

Comment: Are these two functions found in one `script` tag?. You might put this functions in different parts of your PHP file Whereas one part rendered in the page and another may not.

Comment: No, both the functions are under one script tag.

Comment: Is your `console.log(subtot);` displaying?

Comment: @rushikulkarni First thing, Are these two functions defined in inline script tag of a PHP file or in separate js file?

Comment: In one script tag. @SankarRaj

Comment: Yes, it is displaying. @ShadowFiend

Comment: `function SetDefault(a, Text){
   function calcGST()
   { 
   }
   calcGST();
}`

have you tried it like that?

Comment: probably you are calling `calcGST()` from somewhere else also instead of in `SetDefault()`

Comment: No I have not tried that. I will now. @ShadowFiend

Comment: @DhavalPurohit how can that cause this kind of error?

Comment: maybe the `calcGST()` function has not resided in that scope where you are calling.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: @rushikulkarni try to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791248/referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-javascript).. may be that answer can help you..

Comment: I am giving you one example that how the scope works.

if you are defining the function in `ready()` and try to call in some other functions which are not defined in `ready()` function than the other function unable to find the function declared in `ready()`

Comment: Oh ok got it. But in my script I am not defining any thing in ready(), in fact my script does not have ready().

Comment: @ShadowFiend example is also nice to understand the scope things

Comment: ok then just tell  me where else you called the callGST() or its everywhere

Comment: Yep, Its every where.

Comment: try to globalize the function means, try to put the `calcGST()` on the top of everything.